# informatica execute sql in sql transformation

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Background: I am really new. Informatica Developer for PowerCenter Express Version: 9.6.1 HotFix 2

I want to execute a t-sql statement as one step in a work flow:

```
    truncate table dbo.stage_customer
```

I tried create a mapping, add a sql transformation on it.  Input above query in sql query window. I added the mapping to a workflow of just start, the mapping, and the end. When I validate the flow I got this error:

```
    The group [Input] in transformation xxx must have at least one port
```

I have no idea what ports are needed since this (the truncate statement) basically doesn't need input or output.

Comment: Briefly speaking: you're doing it wrong. Informatica is not a "tool to run an sql statement". It's an ETL tool and can be used to create data flows. For that it needs sources and ports and links. It can ALSO perform some additional statements - but it doesn't mean you can throw all other things away.

Comment: no, I am not using it for just running a sql statement, it's a step in a work flow, I will need to truncate a table, populate that table etc.

Comment: In this case simply use a session target property - or a combination of pre/post SQL statements, whichever is best for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you would like to truncate a target table before loading why don't you use the in-built option present in session properties?

goto workflow manager-> open session->mapping tab->click on target table listed left side->choose the property "Truncate table option" just enable it

to answer you question, I think you have to connect at least one input and output port into SQL transformation (because it is not unconnected). Just create dummy ports and try again

try this article - [click here](http://www.folkstalk.com/2012/03/sql-transformation-in-informatica-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use your query "   truncate table dbo.stage_customer" in Pre-SQL command

Comment: I can't find pre-sql command, is it in mapping or workflow? I have tried looking at both but didn't see any. I am using express version btw

Comment: ok, found that in the properties of the source object (Read view). That might work.

Answer (score 1):

As Aswin suggested use the built in option in the session property.

But in the production environments user may not have truncate table access for the table in a database. In this case, informatica workflow will fail if you check the truncate target table option. It is good to have a stored procedure to truncate the target table and use that stored procedure in informatica mapping to avoid workflow failures in case of user having no truncate access to the database.